# Paypal multiple payments

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to write a PHP class for paypal express mutliple payments. All is well so far except one thing I haven't figured out.
In PayPal's docs it says that PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTREQUESTID is a required field for multiple payments, however I have no idea where to obtain a value for it. Is it a user set value? I tried putting random values and PP returns a SUCCESS however I'm not sure if that's good or bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAYMENTREQUESTID is a user set value. The purpose of this field is to allow you co-relate response data for each of your parallel payments with your request data - Therefore it is good enough that this field is unique amongst multiple payment data for a given API call but random numbers should work too. See the [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECParallelPaymens/) for more.

Comment: Thanks. So as I understand it, the values I set can be repeated among different transactions? That is, they only need to be unique between payments of the same transaction.